# Search through part of a string

Tags: c, string, strstr

I am trying to search a string from the middle from index i and get the index of the first instance found, and then change what is stored in the string at this point. I know I can use strstr to search through the string, but this starts at the start of a string. How can I start searching in the middle of the string?

```
int i=5;
char str[]="mystringismystring";
char *pos; 
pos=strstr(str, "my");
int index=pos-str;
```

Comment: Use `str+startpos` instead of `str` to start searching from `startpos`.

Comment: To get the next `"my"`, try `if (pos) pos = strstr(pos + strlen("my"), "my");`

Answer (score 1):

If you always have information about data length you can point to the pointer from where you want like `&str[strlen(str) / 0x2]` or you can put location an array instead of `strlen(str)`.

Code:

```
char str[] = "mystringismystring";
char *pos; 

pos = strstr(&str[strlen(str) / 0x2], "my");
int index = pos - str;
```